# Comparing two tables of local database using C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, compare

I am a newbie in C#.

I created a local database in VS2010(.sdf file). I am trying to create some comparisons between database columns. I successfully connected with the database using the connectionstring below:

```
 string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;data source=c:\\users\\user\\documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\myapp\\myapp\\mydb.sdf";
```

My database has two tables. Nicknames  and Names.
Nicknames has one field called "Alias" which simply lists the nicknames stored.
Names has one field called "Text" which simply lists the names stored.

Ex:

Alias

```
Masher
Jones
Jaime
John
Joker
```

Names

```
John
Adam
Matt
Jones
```

Let's say these are the values in my database. What I want is to find the nicknames who aren't in the table of Names which is -> Masher, Jaime and Joker in my example.

How would i do that? I am using C# and VS2010.

Here is what i tried in terms of SQL codes:

```
 "SELECT Alias FROM nicknames WHERE (NOT (Alias IN(SELECT Text FROM Names))) ";
         "SELECT Alias FROM nicknames EXCEPT SELECT Text FROM Names";
         "SELECT Alias FROM nicknames t LEFT JOIN Names m ON m.Text = t.Alias WHERE m.Text IS NULL";
         "SELECT Alias FROM nicknames UNION SELECT Text FROM Names";
```

What should i do?

### EDIT

```
 OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();
 string sql = "MYQUERYFROMTHEABOVEEXAMPLE";
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
             OleDbDataReader reader;
             reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
             string result = "";
             while (reader.Read())
            {
            result += reader.GetString(0) + "\n";
  }
```

This is what i use to read the results.

Comment: Other's have given you the proper query, but you are asking about C#, do you mean you want to know how to run the query from C#?

Comment: actually the thing is proper queries for this example doesn't work for me. I can't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Its worth noting that you have semi colons at the end of your "SQL Codes", which would mean to me that you are using this in the code behind. I would highly recommend pasting the rest of the code that is used to retrieve the data, because I'm guessing that's your problem.

Comment: Check my edit at the bottom of my post. Your code works fine.

Comment: Glad I could help out, respond to my answer if you need any more help or if you post a similar question on a related topic and I'll take a look. Good luck with your programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT Alias FROM nicknames WHERE Alias not in (SELECT Text FROM Names)
```

Edit: Try this instead:

```
select a.Alias
from nicknames a left outer join Names n on a.alias = n.text 
where n.text IS NULL
```

My attempt @ your code (Ignore the fact I use SQL syntax as that's what I work with):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Select [Alias] from [nicknames] where [Alias] not in (select [text] from [names])
```

should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Then you need to give more information, as that is the exact query that you need to do. The connection string is fairly useless to us code wise, we need to see how you are actually running the command from your code.

Comment: The code looks good, have you just done a select on each table to check that there should be a result. Maybe Nickmanes is empty, or names contains all of the names that are in nicknames.